# Spring boot maven plugin: mvn clean package does not layered jar file automatically

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I got trouble with spring-boot-maven-plugin build process. I just want to build

excutable "**layered**" jar file for optimizing docker image. As document said this build process will produce layered jar by default https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/. Here is apart of my pom.xml file

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <layers>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </layers>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I used spring boot 2.5.5, maven 3.6.3 
Some steps produce:

> mvn clean package 
> jar -tf target/[excutableJarFile].jar

This filesystem of excutableJarFile is just BOOT-INF, META-INF and org although it should be

1. dependencies
2. spring-boot-loader
3. snapshot-dependencies
4. application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enabling the layering feature of the Spring Boot Maven plugin does not change the layout of the generated jar file. It does enable the generation of a `layers.idx` file that describes how the application is layered, as described in the [Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.container-images.layering).

You can use the `layertools` mode of the generated jar to extract the contents of the jar into a layered structure. See the [Dockerfile example in the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.container-images.building.dockerfiles) for more information on how this works.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Actually I splited my docker file into 2 stages - building and copying artifacts from builder to runner. When I ran “docker run” command from runner stage, I encountered error like this “Not found JarLauncher class from org.springboot.loader”. I found that it was just my typo (I typed “Jarlauncher instead of “JarLauncher”) so I thought spring cannot found my entry class because of “ExcutableJarFile” not yet layered. Anyway, your reply is absolute correct that DJarMode=layertools should extract and mapping artifacts to desired layers which defined in index.idx.